# How to prevent formula touch event in MathJax?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

How can I prevent formula touch event in MathJax? e.g. when I touch or click a formula rendered by [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax) It is gone to surround by a blue border as a response that it is touched.
This is an [Example](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/test/sample-all-at-once.html) form MathJax test folder.

[image]

I have already set `showMathMenu: false` but I am unable to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outline is part of the standard browser interface for focusable items on the page.  In version 2.6, MathJax added support for users using assistive technology, and that included making the MathJax menu accessible to keyboard users and those with screen readers. In order for that to work, the math expressions need to be able to accept the browser focus (so that keystrokes will be targeted to them, so the menu can be opened).

The outlines you are seeing are the focus highlighting that is the default styling for focused items in the browser (the actual effect differs between browsers, but all browsers should provide some form of visual indication for the focused item). Without that, keyboard users will not be able to know when and which math expressions are selected for keyboard focus. Removing that would make it harder (or impossible) for those users to properly interact with MathJax and its menus.

While you certainly could add CSS to your page to remove the outlines, it would be a mistake to do so, unless you have no concern for those users who require assistive technology to support their reading of your pages. You should note that all focusable elements should get these outlines (buttons, menus, input areas, etc.) when you click on them. For example, the editor I'm typing into right now has a blue outline indicating that it currently has the keyboard focus.  This is part of the standard interface for focusable items, and is not something you should try to disable.